# Global variable's increasement doesn't work in function

Tags: javascript

I tried to do this, (not the same, this is an example of what i'm doing)

```
var health = 1;

function example(){health++;}

if (health == 2) {alert("done");}
```

But it does not work. It only works if `health++ health==2` in same function. But i don't want to include the `health==2` to the function example. A global, an in function and an out of function (same variable) does not work, i don't know why, can you explain or give me a solution please? Thanks...

**Edited...**

My code can be shown below. What am i missing here?

First

```
var health = 2;
```

Second

```
        function collision6($taskapsa2, $character) {
          var x1 = $taskapsa2.offset().left;
          var y1 = $taskapsa2.offset().top;
          var h1 = $taskapsa2.outerHeight(true);
          var w1 = $taskapsa2.outerWidth(true);
          var b1 = y1 + h1;
          var r1 = x1 + w1;
          var x2 = $character.offset().left;
          var y2 = $character.offset().top;
          var h2 = $character.outerHeight(true);
          var w2 = $character.outerWidth(true);
          var b2 = y2 + h2;
          var r2 = x2 + w2;

          if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return;
     else {if($character.is(":visible")) {
              $("#character").hide();
              if ($("#character").is(':hidden')) {
       // ...
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "OYUNU KAYBETTIN!";
       health++; // here



    }
              $("#mavikutu").show();
              var audio111 = new Audio('kaybedince.wav');
              audio111.play();
            } }

        }


    window.setInterval(function() {
        $('#result').text(collision6($('#taskapsa2'), $('#character')));
    }, 200);
```

And third

```
collision6();
if (health==3){alert("abc");}
```

Comment: You're not calling the function.

Comment: It should work if you put `example();` before the last line.

Comment: That if statement most likely needs to live inside of the example() method.... Or you need to have code that checks the variable or use event messaging. That if is NOT going to magically keep checking.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `collision6()` function without any parameters but in the function declaration it expects 2 parameters that are required to modify the health variable.

You need to pass in `$taskapsa2` and  `$character` arguments to the collision6 function.

Comment: I tried to do this, but it doesn't work again, should i copy/paste my original code here?

Comment: If i am correctly understand you, i wrote it like this >>> collision6($taskapsa2, $character); in the last line, but it does not work again...

Comment: You need to pass in the variables of the 2 elements that are doing the collision.  We would need to see the rest of your code to know what those are.